# How can I show "Only X left" on configurable products on Magento 2.2.8?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, configurable-swatches

I want to know how I can show the function "Only X left" on configurable products on magento 2. I've tried so many ways, but nothing works. I see how to do this to M1, but nothing to M2.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in Backend store configuration,

> Catalog -> Inventory -> Stock Options -> Only X left in Threshold

set the value you want, it will solve your problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It don't works to configurable products.

Comment: These links are for M1 :/

Comment: that's my bad, let me see more if i can find anything